# Read binary data from Buffer

Tags: node.js

I am trying to examine the binary data given a Buffer like so:

```
<Buffer 08 30 66 6d 41 64 69 76 66>
```

TMK that is 8 bytes of data.

What I am looking to do is examine the first byte, and look at the most significant bit (leftmost bit) in that first byte.

How can I find out if that first bit is a zero or one?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is this:

```
Number(buf[0] > 127)
```

Works because:

1. JS treats bytes as unsigned, AKA always positive; a byte's value is thus in the range **[0..255]**, as opposed to **[-128..127]** for signed bytes.
2. Number(true) == **1**, Number(false) == **0**
3. the most significant bit is **1** only when byte is in range **[128..255]**

(Bonus) A harder to read but sexier version:

```
((buf[0] & 0xff) >> 7)
```